# adjusting div in html

Tags: css, html

I am new to html. I want to make simple layout design as follows:

```
-------------------------------------
                                    |
-------------------------------------
    |                           |   |
    |                           |   |
    |                           |   |
    |                           |   |
    |---------------------------|   |
____|_________footer____________|___|
```

but my footer is not adjusted in between left and right menu. It is below left and right menu.

Below is my html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: aqua;
    position: relative;
}

#header {
    height: 5%;
    background-color: #FFA500;
}

#leftmenu {
    background-color: #FFD700;
    height: 90%;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}

#rightmenu {
    background-color: #FFD700;
    height: 90%;
    width: 10%;
    float: left;
}

#content {
    style ="background-color: #EEEE12;
    height: 85%;
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
}
</style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title><tiles:insertAttribute name="title" ignore="true"></tiles:insertAttribute>
</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" class=".container">

        <div id="header" class=".header">
            <h1>Main Title of Web Page</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="leftmenu" class=".leftmenu">
            <b>Menu</b><br> HTML<br> CSS<br> JavaScript
        </div>

        <div id="content" class=".content">Content goes here</div>

        <div id="rightmenu" class=".rightmenu">
            <b>DashBoard</b><br> Recent<br> Saved Search
        </div>

        <div id="footer"
            style="background-color: #FFA500; clear: both; text-align: center;">
            Copyright Â© W3Schools.com</div>

    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this should get you started. i moved your footer inside the `content` div http://jsfiddle.net/Ur4Me/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems

The first is that you are mixing inline CSS with CSS in a `<style>` tag. Don't do that, just put it in the `<style>` tag 99.9% of the time

Secondly, you have a `style="...` in one line of your CSS, presumably from copying so I removed it

Thirdly, you need to set a width for the footer. Since the two side divs are both percents that total 30%, I changed the footer to have `width:70%`

Fourthly you need to position it to the right of the left div. You can do so by using `margin-left:20%`, the width of that left div

Lastly, you need to position the footer up next to the left and right divs. By using my browsers inspect element I saw that the footer was 20px. Thus I gave the two side divs both `margin-bottom:-20px` so that the `clear:float` on the footer wouldn't make it go past both elements

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/dafiyaja/1/edit)

Although this isn't the way I'd do it, it works

Comment: Thanks for such nice and detailed explanation. Your explanation helped in understanding things.

Answer (score 3):

So what I've done here is create a **middle** div.  That contains your content and footer.

Your middle div has a relative position, and I've absolutely positioned your footer to sit at the bottom.

Note, the middle div needs a height for this to work.  That shouldn't be an issue though!

Let me know if you need anything else!

```
<div id="middle"> 
<div id="content" class=".content">Content goes here</div>
<div id="footer" style="background-color: #FFA500; clear: both; text-align: center;">
Copyright Â© W3Schools.com
</div>
</div>
</div>

#middle {float: left; width: 70%; height: 80px; position: relative;}
#footer {bottom: 0px; position: absolute; width: 100%}
```

Here's a fiddle with an example for you!

**http://jsfiddle.net/LmVKD/**

Comment: Is position:absolute safe for cross-browserness and mobile?

Comment: It's a standard piece of CSS.  Will work in every browser / mobile browser.  I'd not advise using it on everything, but in the case it seems fine.  As the footer would only be absolutely positioned inside the middle div as the middle div has been positioned relatively.

Comment: This is the way I'd do it most likely